# F# Idiomatic Index plus one when printing an index

Tags: f#, idioms

Is there a more idiomatic way to print an index +1 value with F#?

```
let plusOne i = i + 1
let collection = [1..10]

collection |> List.iteri (fun index value -> printfn "%i %i" (plusOne index) value)
```

Comment: Why not just `collection |> List.iteri (fun index value -> printfn "%i %i" (index + 1) value)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F# does have many special idioms but that doesn’t mean it breaks the very common idiom in which indices of list/array... start from zero.

So, to answer to question: no, F# does not have any special idiom for index plus.

However, if you are intending to often iter a list with index plus one, you can use Active Pattern to implicitly increase the index right in the parameter declaration, like this:

```
let (|Inc|) = (+) 1
let collection = [1..10]
collection |> List.iteri (fun (Inc i) value -> printfn "%i %i" i value)
```